# Reading from file line by line in c++(each line has one string and several int values)?

Tags: c++, ifstream

(the number of integers in each line is the same, but it is unknown)

So I may have a file like this:

```
title1 34 98 
title2 15 9 
title3 45 15
```

or

```
title1 34 98 76 97
title2 15 9 43 8
title3 45 15 34 7
```

or ...

```
struct elem
{
  char d[50];
  int v[50];
};
```

I tried this and it compiles but doesn't work

```
char ch;
elem col[10];
int num,z=0;

//z-nr of lines, num -nr of int values in the line

ifstream myfile("t2.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile.good())
{
      myfile>>col[z].d;
  num=0;
  myfile.get(ch);
  while(ch!='\n')
  {
        myfile>>col[z].v[num];
    myfile.get(ch);
    num++;
      }
  z++;
}
  myfile.close();
}
```

the program 'hangs' (the not responding state)

Comment: In what way does it not work? I can see that you have a potential buffer overflows but I suspect that this isn't what you talk about...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Read file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile("t2.txt");

if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);

        iss >> col[z].d;

        int x;
        num = 0;
        while (iss >> x) {
            col[z].v[num] = x;
            num++; 
        }

        z++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot, it does work, but there is this problem: I'm doing an MFC application project(using the values from the text file as input) and after I execute it it's all right, but if I resize the output window ,z(the nr of lines, increases with each resize , so it's 3,6,9...)